# How to set callback function on submit button in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I use `bootstrap` modal dialog as the user register form as below:

```
<form>
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 class="modal-title" id="signupModalLabel">Sign Up</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user-name-input">User Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-name-input" placeholder="User Name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user-email-input">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="user-email-input" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="userPasswordInput">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="user-password-input" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" id="signup-submit-button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

it works fine and I want to add callback function for the submit button. I need to call a web socket request on that callback. If I do it as below:

```
$("#signup-submit-button").click(signup);

const signup = () => {
    // make a web socket call
}
```

the callback function `signup` can be called but all form input validations don't work. Each `input` in the form has a `required` attribute. If I leave this blank bootstrap validation should be triggered to validate the form value.

How can I add a callback after pass validation check?

Comment: You need to use preventDefault();

$("#signup-submit-button").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
signup_whatever();
});

Comment: If I put `event.preventDefault()`, it will not trigger the validation.

Comment: You need to manually trigger/call the validation function. Check if(username.val() !="" || password.val()!=""){} before continuing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **onsubmit** event inside form tag. This will allow validation rules to be checked before executing **signup()** function. Please note, if you want to suppress validation, then you can add **novalidate** attributes to form tag too.

```js
function signup() {

}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="signup()">
      ...      
</form>
```

**Updated : Working solution**

```js
$('#signup-submit-button').on('click', function() {   $(this).parents('form:first').find('.hiddenButton').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 class="modal-title" id="signupModalLabel">Sign Up</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user-name-input">User Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-name-input" placeholder="User Name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user-email-input">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="user-email-input" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="userPasswordInput">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="user-password-input" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="hiddenButton" style="display:none"></button>
                        <button type="button" id="signup-submit-button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: What if the `signup` function is not global function. It is set in a separate module.

Comment: Then there are multiple ways to do it, out which one is to add **onsubmit** event programatically via JavaScript. Or,  force form to submit using **submit** method of form on click of button.

Comment: Please, find my edited answer with working solution.

Comment: was the answer useful? If yes, would you mind voting up.

Answer (score 1):

This seems working fine for me

```js
$("#signup-submit-button").click(signup);

var signup = () => {
    // make a web socket call
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 class="modal-title" id="signupModalLabel">Sign Up</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user-name-input">User Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-name-input" placeholder="User Name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user-email-input">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="user-email-input" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="userPasswordInput">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="user-password-input" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" id="signup-submit-button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: If I do this, the validation doesn't work on bootstrap

Comment: @ZhaoYi Would you mind to share full code? We can help you in better way. I mean share `signup()` and `validation` code.

Comment: the signup() code is empty. The validation part is defined in the html. You can see that each input field has a `required` attribute which indicating it is a required validation

Comment: @ZhaoYi Edited my answer and it seems that the problem is with `const` keyword at least over fiddle

Comment: I have checked your demo. If the validation failed, the signup function is still called. How can I prevent calling signup if validation failed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#signup-submit-button").click(function() {
  signup(function() {
    alert("callback is called")
  })
});

function signup(callback) {
  alert("function before callback")
  callback();
}
```

This will run the code inside `function signup` first and then fire the callback after

**demo**

```js
$("#signup-submit-button").click(function() {
  signup(function() {
    alert("callback is called")
  })
});

function signup(callback) {
  alert("function before callback")
  callback();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="signupModalLabel">Sign Up</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="user-name-input">User Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-name-input" placeholder="User Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="user-email-input">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="user-email-input" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="userPasswordInput">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="user-password-input" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" id="signup-submit-button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I want to use bootstrap validation but the signup callback remove the validation logic